# Accessing mongoDB using mongoose on production server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When i run node server.js on production server ,mongodb connection established with proper success message. but, any query not get executed while execution. After some time of loading the page getting error 502.

```
var mongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname'
```

Comment: change it to 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbname'  maybe works

Comment: I did that also but couldn't work. The connection is already established but the problem is i can not execute any query. On development server i can execute every query though.

Comment: CAn you use Mongo Shell ?

Comment: @Kishor did u made it work ?